# How to change default bridge subnet for nerdctl

Tags: containerd

With `nerdctl`, I can change the subnet of the default bridge in `/etc/cni/net.d/nerdctl-bridge.conflist` to, e.g., 100.64.0.0/24. However, `nerdctl` still assigns 10.4.0.0/24 for new bridges (`nerdctl network create foo`).

How can I configure `nerdctl` to start at another base subnet?